# Convert a List of strings into ints in a 2d list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I convert:

```
TownCordList = [['1', '2', '2'], ['2', '1', '2']]
```

Into

```
TownCordList= [[1,2,2],[2,1,2]]
```

I have tried:

```
for i in TownCordList:
i = list(map(int,i))
```

But that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently overwriting the variable `i` in every iteration of your loop so basically you are storing nothing after conversion. Instead, you can use a list comprehension as

```
TownCordList = [list(map(int, i)) for i in TownCordList]
# [[1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 2]]
```